# multiple GO projects on the same server

Tags: go

in PHP you can have a project in `/var/www/htdocs/project1` another in `/var/www/htdocs/project2`  etc...

but how can i do it in Go?

option 1) 1 executable for every project. but you would need open a different port for every project so project1 would be `http://localhost:3000` , project2: `http://localhost:3001`  but what happens if you have 1000 projects? do you open 1000 ports? i think that isnt a good practice

option 2) 1 executable for all the projects (1 main.go to rule all of them!).
you would need to do something like :

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/project1/users", projectOneUsers)
    http.HandleFunc("/project2/users", projectTwoUsers)
    http.HandleFunc("/project3/users", projectThreeUsers)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

but you would need to recompile all the projects everytime that you change one of them. bad idea

option 3) ???

What is the best way to do it?

thanks

Comment: Obviously you need a reverse-proxy that knows what "domain" goes where (in this case which port). Are you going to build a netflix that you need 1000 sites? In your PHP example Apache (or NGINX) is taking care which site you get not the PHP itself. You need the same for GoLang or any other language. If you run [PHP internal server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) you will discover that it has same *flaw* as `http.ListenAndServe`.

Comment: If you run 1000 non-trivial projects on one server you either have a server that beefy that you will know how to do this kind of stuff or you have a different set of problems.

Comment: excatly what do you mean by a project because a 1000 projects sounds like a number no one will ever reach

Answer (score 1):

1. There is nothing inherently wrong with opening a thousand ports. There are 65k to choose from, after all (per IP address!). However, running one thousand services on a single host is an operational nightmare. You wouldn't want that big of an interruption every time a kernel update is due, for instance. There's also the matter of resource contention, system tuning, and attack surface.
2. The Go compiler is smart and quick. It won't compile everything all the time. Don't jump to conclusions.
3. Long before your software reaches that kind of size (if ever), you will have automation in place that solves this problem for you. Do whatever is most practical for you right now and change infrastructure if and when required.

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 could be a load balancer that acts as a reverse proxy. In that case you need not to expose any bound port to the outside. It is sufficient when the load balancer you access each started go app.

Comment: Do you think this question belongs to SO? Isn't it a bit low quality? Isn't it that OP does not understand why PHP works but GO won't (that easily - without the proxy?).

Comment: That is a good point. I think it could be seen as only just valid, as the problem is described from a (php) programmer's view.

Comment: See my updated comment on the OP. OP just fails to realise that they have Apache sitting in front of the PHP and OP wants the same for Go. Your answer is valid of course, OP should rephrase a bit maybe. I don't know its just a bit odd question. OP got spoiled by PHP world having LAMP out of box or MAMP or Valet or whatever that has this setup from the beginning.